# Prove limit using the Epsilon-Delta definition

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Prove limit using the Epsilon-Delta definition:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(2,4)}x^2+2x-y=4$$
I've been trying to solve this by completing the square so i can get something like: $$|a(x-2)+b(y-4)|$$ The solution would be trivial then, but i haven't had any luck, perhaps I'm missing something.

Some insight on how to solve it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you start by writing the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, and plug in your expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your work, it suffices to notice that

\begin{align*}
\|(x,y) - (2,4)\|_{2} & = \sqrt{(x-2)^{2} + (y-4)^{2}} < \delta_{\varepsilon} \\\\
&\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
|x - 2| < \delta_{\varepsilon}\\\\
|y - 4| < \delta_{\varepsilon}
\end{cases}\\\\
& \Rightarrow |a(x-2)| + |b(y-4)| \leq (|a| + |b|)\delta_{\varepsilon} := \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: This would work if the OP knew what these values of $a$ and $b$ were. But the OP said he/she hasn't been able to determine these values.

Comment: Thank you for the response but that's exactly what I know, perhaps my wording was wrong, but my problem lies on how to get from $|x^2+2x−y-4|$ to the $|a(x-2)+b(y-4)|$ form.

Comment: If your problem lies in going from $x^2+2x-y-4$ to $a(x-2)+b(y-4)$ wouldn't this mean you *don't* know these values? I would write $x^2+2x-y-4$ as $(x+4)(x-2)+(4-y)$ then follow the hint made by @user0102